# Como recuperar dados json de uma URL utilizando HTTP POST no android?

Tags: android

Preciso recuperar valores `Json` de uma determinada URL utilizando `HTTP POST`, porém estou com dificuldades para começar. 
Como posso realizar tal operação no Android?

Comment: Olá ! Você quer fazer com HttpPost do Java, ou pode usar alguma biblioteca para isto?

Comment: Tenho persentimento que ele também não vai saber responder sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

No Android podemos utilizar algumas bibliotecas para no auxiliar nesta tarefa como o [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/index.html) ou [Okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Vou mostrar um exemplo com Okhttp:

Vamos adicionar as bibliotecas no **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0' 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3' // Tranforma Json para Objeto
}
```

Para realizar uma requisição, temos que separa-lá da `Thread` principal, para que não interfira na interface gráfica:

```
 private final class Send extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        final Context mContext;
        Send(final Context mContext)
        {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                final OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody body = null;
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
                requestBuilder.url("www.url.com.br/send");
                final HashMap<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<>(0);

                mParams.put("param1", "Valo1" );
                mParams.put("param4", "Valor2" );
                mParams.put("param3", "Valor3" );

                final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mParams);
                body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonObject.toString());
                requestBuilder.post(body);
                OkHttpModel.loadHeaders(requestBuilder, mContext);

            try{
                final Response response = mClient.newCall(requestBuilder.build()).execute();
                final String txtResult = response.body().string();

                MeuObjeto meuObjeto = new Gson().fromJson(txtResult, MeuObjeto.class);


            }catch (final IOException e){ }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

O `MeuObjeto` deve conter os mesmo parametros do Json retornado pela requisição, e o mesmo nome:

```
     class MeuObjeto{

            private String valor_1;

            private Integer valor_2;

            private Boolean status;


// Get's and Set's

        }
```

Se os nomes forem diferentes, podemos mapear com Annotation:

```
class MeuObjeto{

    @SerializedName("valor_1")
    private String valor1;

    @SerializedName("valor_2")
    private Integer valor2;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private Boolean valor3;

// Get's and Set's
}
```

Qualquer dúvida, estamos a disposição!